# Add 'where' clausures dynamically to linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this linq query:

```
var query = (from dc in context.Table1.Include(d => d.Doc)
                         join u in _context.Table2 on dc.IDDoc equals u.IDDoc
                         where dc.ID == id && u.IDUser == user.IDUser
                         select dc)
                        .Union(from dc in context.Table1.Include(d => d.Doc)
                               join p in _context.Table3 on dc.IDDoc equals p.IDDoc
                               where dc.ID == id
                               select dc);
```

And I want to add more where conditions dynamically depends of a list (List ids)
What I want to achieve is something like this:

Imagine that I have a List ids = new(){1, 2, 5, 27);
What I want to do is to add that info into this part of the query to have something like this:

```
.Union(from dc in context.Table1.Include(d => d.Doc)
      join p in _context.Table3 on dc.IDDoc equals p.IDDoc
      where dc.ID == id && p.ID == 1 || p.ID == 2 || p.ID == 5 || p.ID = 27
      select dc)
```

But if next time list is List ids = new(){4}, query should look like:

```
.Union(from dc in context.Table1.Include(d => d.Doc)
          join p in _context.Table3 on dc.IDDoc equals p.IDDoc
          where dc.ID == id && p.ID == 4 
          select dc)
```

Is it even possible? If not, what would be a possible solution?
Thank you

EDIT: I made up with this query because I have no clue about how to add it to my main query.
What I really have is this:

```
var mainQuery = _context.RootTable
            .Include(i => i.Items).ThenInclude(dc => dc.Docs)
            .Include(i => i.Items).ThenInclude(sg => sg.Signs)
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID== id);
```

And what I want to do is to filter the ".ThenInclude(dc => dc.Docs) with the other query. I can't figure out how to do it in a better and efficient way that with two sepparate queries.

Comment: You should really reconsider this query. You aren't using embedded SQL, you're using a query language over EF Core. There are no tables, there are entities with relations. You shouldn't have to write any JOINs, the ORM will generate them from relations, object and collection properties as needed. You shouldn't have to use UNION either. In the typical Blog and Posts example, you can retrieve the posts of a specific blog with just `ctx.Blog.Where(b=>b.ID=123).Select(b=>b.Posts)`. No JOINs are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0):

```cs
List<int> ids = new(){4};
....
   .Union(from dc in context.Table1.Include(d => d.Doc)
          join p in _context.Table3 on dc.IDDoc equals p.IDDoc
          where dc.ID == id && ids.Contains(p.ID) // here 
          select dc)
....
```

Comment: You can simplify your work even more if you use EF Core as an ORM instead of embedded SQL. You could get rid of all the JOINs at least

Comment: @Weenhallo would not mind one if it would be possible) Note that Panagiotis makes a very good point about overall approach to handling queries via ORMs like EF.

Comment: Could you make me an example with my code? I'm still learning and sometimes it feels like banging my head against a wall

Comment: I have this query: var query= _context.RootTable
            .Include(d=> d.Doc)
            .Include(m=> m.Markers).ThenInclude(d=> d.Docs)
            .Include(m=> m.Markers).ThenInclude(s=> s.Sigs)
            .FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == id);  And then, I wrote my other query to filter the Docs included in Markers. It would be great if could combine both but I tried yesterday without any luck

Comment: @Weenhallo if you are using EF Core 5+ version you can use [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include), at least in some cases, read the caution carefully cause in some cases it can give strange results.